# vimeo API - Store value in variable

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo, froogaloop, vimeo-player

I'm struggling with Vimeo's Froogaloop API.

I'm working on a web-based game and I need that, before a user enters the next level, he watches an entire video (not longer than 3 minutes).

I thought I could use a while loop where as long as the current time's value is less than the video's duration, it keeps getting the current time to evaluate. When the values match, a button that links to the next level is unlocked. To do so, I have to store the getCurrentTime and getDuration values inside javascript variables.

So far it seems easy but apparently Froogaloop needs callback function with get methods and I can't manage to save them properly into variables.

```
function getDuration(playerID,value) {
            Froogaloop(playerID).api('getDuration',function(dur) {
                    value(dur);
                });    
            }

            var durata = getDuration(playerID,function(value){
                          var length = value;
                          return(length);
                         });
}
```

But this way the "durata" variable returns undefined. Am I missing anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because the API is asynchronous, you cannot return the value synchronously. If you're playing the video until the end, I'd recommend using the `finish` event instead of testing the current time and duration.

That would look something like this:

```
$f(playerID).addEvent('finish', function() {
    // video has finished playing here
    goToNextLevel();
});
```